# Что лучше в PHP: хранение медиа в фолдере или long BLOB

Tags: php, mysql

Как лучше хранить картинки в PHP? Как будет лучше для pagespeed?

Comment: у вас какие-то собственные мысли по этому поводу есть? Вот рассмотрите две ситуации, когда одна картина на диске, другая в базе и перечислите действия необходимые для ее доставке клиенту.

Comment: Когда в базе - дольше, но это может я что-то не так делаю? размер тот же, что и на диске, даже меньше, но зависает страница хорошенько